How to handle recurring questions?
This week alone, I have seen at least three questions that boil down to "How do I use a paper wallet in order to store bitcoins offline?" 
Since there seem to be several FAQ like that which keep coming up again and again, it would be great to create one extensive answer for each of them, to which then could just be referred. (Or hopefully, they would even be found before the question gets asked again.)
So, I was wondering: What is the proper way to go about that? How do other SE handle that sort of question? What would be the best way to refer all these questions to one best answer?
Edit:
Here are some examples for the mentioned question.
Secure way to store BTC over a long time - and its risks?
Backing up wallet with pen and paper, destroying electronic copy, restoring from keyboard -- how?
How do I make a Bitcoin "memory wallet" (or paper wallet without paper)?
Is it possible to make a paper wallet out of a bitcoin-qt wallet?
Write down bitcoins on a piece of paper
How to save bitcoins as paper?

I guess, basically I am asking whether there are some good case practices how to make this SE more readable. :)
